# Stunnel - Specify Outbound IP?

Tags: stunnel

Is there any way to specify a particular outbound IP address for stunnel?  Right now, it's always using the main IP of the server, but I'd like it to use a specific outbound IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found my own answer on this one - the "local" directive.

```
local = host
    IP of the outgoing interface is used as source for remote connections.
    Use this option to bind a static local IP address, instead.
```